# Is the maximum value at 4 hearts?

Tags: stack-egg

Is there any reason to try to 'increase' something when it's already shown at 4 hearts? For example, if `Questions` is at 4 hearts, could I try to increase the `Questions` value or slow decay with `Ask`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 4 hearts are the maximum for each stat. But it's worth voting a stat that has reached 4 hearts, because if a stat remains inactive for a while its value will decrease.

Comment: Normally a stat will decrease after being inactive for 4 days.  Users will decrease faster if you've been downvoting, and Quality will decrease faster if you have high Traffic.

Comment: @Brilliand Didn't notice that there was a fixed amount of days, and I think it's too late to verify that.

Answer (score -2):

No, unless everything is filled up. When everything is filled up, ask. Here is the order of what to do:

1: Increase Questions to 4
2: Increase Answers to 4
3: Increase Quality to 3
4: Increase Users to 4
5: Increase Quality to 4

Doing this way, winning will be easy and Traffic will go up to 4 if you keep filling up the most important stats (Questions -> Answers -> Quality -> Users)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question... this is about mechanics, not strategy.